# magento2 create menu in frontend

Tags: magento2.3

i want to add a page in menu. How can i create it?

[image]

Please help me!

Comment: Using programmatically???

Comment: yes can i use the code to create it? Should i create file xml?

Comment: check this link --- https://linkstraffic.net/adding-custom-menu-item-inside-magento2/

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand this page very well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply above link talking to add the simple sort code in your `topmenu.phtml`. So You go to your `topmenu.phtml` file and put the some code

```
<li class="level0 nav-8 last level-top ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a href="yoururl" class="level-top ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-9" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"><span>A TITLE</span></a></li>
```

After your,

```
delete all files in `var/view_preprocessing` 
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```

And see the **output**

[image]

Hope this help you

Thanks ...

Answer (score 2):

Need to create custom module.

- In app/code/{{vendor}}/{{modulename}}/etc/di.xml - add following code.

  ```xml
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <!-- Add Plugin for add custom link in navigation -->
  <type name="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu">
      <plugin name="add_menu_item_plugin" type="<vendor>\<modulename>\Plugin\TopmenuAfterPlugin" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
  </type>
  </config>
  ```
- Now create TopmenuAfterPlugin.php file here app/code/{{vendor}}/{{modulename}}/Plugin folder with following code.

```
<?php
    namespace {{vendor}}\{{modulename}}\Plugin;
     class TopmenuAfterPlugin
    {
        public function afterGetHtml(\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu $topmenu, $html)
        {
            $customUrl = $topmenu->getUrl('testmenu/menu');//here you can set link
            $magentoCurrentUrl = $topmenu->getUrl('*/*/*', ['_current' => true, '_use_rewrite' => true]);
            if (strpos($magentoCurrentUrl,'testmenu/menu') !== false) {
                $html .= "<li class=\"level0 nav-5 active level-top parent ui-menu-item\">";
            } else {
                $html .= "<li class=\"level0 nav-4 level-top parent ui-menu-item\">";
            }
            $html .= "<a href=\"" . $customUrl . "\" class=\"level-top ui-corner-all\"><span class=\"ui-menu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-e\"></span><span>" . __("Custom Menu") . "</span></a>";
            $html .= "</li>";
            return $html;
        }
    }
```